# Cannot find extension method: "Cannot find a parameter with this name"

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Using Jetpack Compose, I'm trying to us the `LazyListScope.items(..)` that takes an `items` `List`.

```
val messages: List<Message> = ...
LazyColumn {
  items(items = messages) { message ->
    MessageCard(message)
  }
}
```

> Cannot find a parameter with this name: items

[The tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial) doesn't specify the `items` parameter name, but without it, Kotlin only finds the `LazyListScope.items(..)` that expects a `count`:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is List but Int was expected

Answer (score 4):

The `items` extension methods have to be imported:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
```

With that, the `items =` parameter name is not explicitly necessary, as the `List<Message>` type has a distinct function prototype match.